# Is my grammar checker missing an obvious grammar error?

Tags: grammar

I am a non-native English speaker, and I have used this (paid) grammar checker for some time now. The tool is called LanguageTool. Today I noticed the tool is potentially missing an obvious grammar mistake, but I am not 100% sure. Shouldn't "have" be "has" in the sentence below?

[image]

Comment: It should be **has** obviously.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I would mistrust such an app, at least regarding translation.

Comment: All grammar checkers are low quality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your grammar checker is wrong in this instance.  I would use Grammarly.  Typically I won't promote any product because I don't believe in product promotion however in this case I think Grammarly does an excellent job.

Comment: *I won't promote any product because I don't believe in product promotion, however in this case I think Grammarly does an excellent job.* -- **Apophasis** is a rhetorical device wherein the speaker or writer brings up a subject by either denying it, or denying that it should be brought up.

Comment: @Greybeard **Quoting out of context** occurs when one omits content (here, "Typically") that changes the meaning of a quotation. There is no apophasis here; the meaning is "I recommend so few products that the current recommendation carries notable weight."

Comment: @Chemomechanics I will not mention your skill as an apologist... :)